# How to incrementially concatenate ranges?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

### Background

What I am trying to do is to implement some classes that represents geometry. Any instance of a geometry class has a method called `vertices()` that returns a non-owning view of vertices. A geometry class can be expressed in terms of multiple other geometry classes, so the geometry class' `vertices()`-method would ideally just do something like this (pseudocode):

```
vertices()
{
  return join(part1.vertices(), part2.vertices(), part3.vertices());
}
```

subject to not copying nor moving vertices.

In C++20 this is something that I *believe* can be done with ranges & views but I can't figure out how to do it.

### My attempt

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

struct Vertex { float x, y, z; };

struct GeometryA {
    auto vertices() {
        return std::ranges::ref_view(v);
    }
    std::vector<Vertex> v {{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}};
};

struct GeometryB {
    auto vertices() {
        return std::ranges::ref_view(v);
    }
    std::vector<Vertex> v {{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}};
};

struct GeometryC {
    auto vertices() {
        // OK: All elements of vector are of same type
        return std::vector{ a.vertices(), b.vertices(), std::ranges::ref_view(v)} | std::views::join;
    }
    GeometryA a;
    GeometryB b;
    std::vector<Vertex> v {{0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}};
};

struct GeometryD {
    auto vertices() {
        // Compilation fails: Elements of vector have different types
        return std::vector{ c.vertices(), std::ranges::ref_view(v)} | std::views::join;
    }
    GeometryC c;
    std::vector<Vertex> v {{1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}};
};

int main() {
    GeometryD d;

    for(Vertex const& vertex : d.vertices()) {
        // Should print {0,0,1} {0,1,0} {0,1,1} {1,0,0} {1,0,1}
        std::cout << "{" << vertex.x << "," << vertex.y << "," << vertex.z << "} ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails in `GeometryD::vertices` since I am trying to deduce the template parameter `T` of the outmost vector from the elements at initialization (`c.vertices()` and `std::ranges::ref_view(v)`) but these do not have the same type hence `T` can't be deduced.

I am at a loss on how to approach this problem.

### Question

Is it possible to use the standard ranges library to incrementally concatenate ranges?

---

I suppose I could gather all vertex-data directly or indirectly owned by a geometry class by using some recursive template-trickery and then just use `std::views::join` *once*, but before I get my hands dirty with that I'd like to get some input on my current attempt.

Comment: Uses `views::all(v)` instead of `std::ranges::ref_view(v)`.

Comment: Using views::all(v) causes copying / moving to take place which violates my requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Eric Niebler's [Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) library.

Just concat the different range views with `ranges::views::concat`. E.g., for `GeometryC`:

```cpp
return ranges::views::concat(a.vertices(), b.vertices(), v);
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/6dx4Krb3a)

Much of the Range-v3's stuff is being gradually adopted by the standard Ranges library, although it seems this feature hasn't made it yet.

Comment: Yes, it can be done Range-v3. [Here's a godbolt-example that shows this](https://godbolt.org/z/s97cn78s1).

I do however ask for if this can be done with the standard ranges library presently, but I believe that this is not possible (yet). Your answer answer is the best one I am gonna get, accepting.

Comment: Thanks! Notice the [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6dx4Krb3a) link in my answer takes you to a Godbolt exampel as well; although the `vertices` methods in that example return a `ranges::ref_view` instead of a `std::vector<Vertex>&`. `concat` is not yet part of the `std`. Here's a [plan](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html) for incorporating some ranges features to the `std`.